# Using of plural noun compound + noun

Tags: grammar, word-usage

What is the correct usage of the phrase if I want to name something, in this case is a component which is a dialog window of column settings (web development).
"Column Settings Dialog" or "Column Setting Dialog"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what the dialog contains. If it contains multiple setting**s**, it is a "column setting**s** dialog". If it contains one setting, it is a "column setting dialog". The plural "column settings dialog" is also much more common in technical writing.